# Is it valid for XSD to define a complex element as compulsory but all children elements are optional?

Tags: xml, xsd

I am trying to write a XML generator from a set of xpaths and values. And the generated XML needs to be valid according to its XSD. So an example is like below

XSD. XSD version is 1.0.

```xml
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="products">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="books">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="book" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="cards" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="card" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

According to the XSD, the `cards` is required. Although no card is not required with `minOccurs="0"`.

The set of xpaths and the values are in a CSV file. The values may be from database, so it is not guaranteed to have `cards`.

```
/products/books/book[0],book1_name
/products/books/book[1],book2_name
```

Generated XML

```xml
<products>
    <books>
        <book>book1_name</book>
        <book>book2_name</book>
    </books>
</products>
```

So the XML is not valid for its XSD because `cards` node is not there.

- In terms of XSD, is it valid to make the parent (`cards`) compulsory, but all children (`card`) optional?
- In terms of the meaning of XML, does it make sense to have `cards` but without any children or value?

Comment: Why do you think that'd be not valid?

Comment: What is your XSD version: 1.0 or 1.1?

Comment: This question, without a specific example, is merely inviting people to express an opinion. That is not what StackOverflow is for. If you have a specific scenario in mind, please provide it and take time to explain your question in full.

Comment: @kimbert, the example is added in the post. Thanks for the reading the post.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky, The XSD version is 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the explanation - it really helps to understand what the overall task is.

> In terms of XSD, is it valid to make the parent (cards) compulsory, but all children (card) optional?

Yes, it is valid. The XML Schema specification does not require a complex element to have any content. There are ways to check that an XSD is valid btw. Most XSD processors (including Java) will check an XSD when they load it. Be careful though - some XML Schema validity rules are not implemented in all processors (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_Particle_Attribution)

> In terms of the meaning of XML, does it make sense to have cards but without any children or value?

Of course. It's exactly equivalent to having a non-null array containing zero elements.
Why did you think that it did not make sense?